# PHPMailer Cannot Send

Tags: php, gmail

Cannot send mail (I enable the `extension=php_openssl.dll` // for email)
and my php version is 5.4.12

Error:

```
SMTP -> ERROR: Failed to connect to server: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. (10060)
SMTP Connect() failed.
Mailer Error: SMTP Connect() failed.
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that SSL support is enabled, so just enable `extension=php_openssl.dll`

and you could also try to use `$mail->SMTPDebug = 1;`

if it doesn't work you can try

```
// if you're using SSL
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
// OR use TLS
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
```

Comment: try this // if you're using SSL `$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';` // OR use TLS `$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';`

Comment: was it working earlier, what version of phpmailer you're using??

Comment: Your ISP May be blocking access to third-party SMTP Servers. A lot of ISPs block them and force their customers to use their own SMTP servers instead.

Comment: Software: PHPMailer - PHP email class                                    Version: 5.1

Comment: how do i allow the isp?

Comment: contact your ISP customer support

Comment: As I've mentioned earlier, A lot of ISPs block them and force their customers to use their own SMTP servers instead. It could be one of the reason for the error you've mentioned.